# How do I show only Things with Username of "abc"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

I have a Thing model:

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => '300x300>', :thumb => '100x100>' }

  validates :image, presence: true
  validates :description, presence: true
end
```

I also have a User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :things

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :username, presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true
end
```

My UsersController looks like this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
  end
end
```

When I navigate to localhost:3000/users/Delacram, where Delacram is the username, how do I display only the Things with a username of Delacram?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you have the `@user` that has many `things`:

```
@user.things
```

You can loop on it:

```
@user.things.each do |thing|
  = thing.description
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

also... in the controller, you can call an instance of `@things = @user.things`.  Then in your view, you can call `= render @things`.  This will look to `views/things/_thing.html.haml`, and plop whatever's in that file onto the page for each instance of @thing.

Rails magic...